# How is the arrow function(which is an argument), accepting the value of x as 1 and returning it?

Tags: javascript, console.log, arrow-functions, iife, hoisting

```
console.log((function(x, f = () => x) {
  var x;
  var y = x;
  x = 2;
  return [x, y, f()];
})(1));
```

This is the code snippet. The output here is (3) [2, 1, 1]
How is the third output 1 and not 2?

Also, if I run this code on Scratch JS, it prints (3) [2, 1, 2]

Why is the output different here?

I tried passing a second argument in the  IIFE function as in:

```
console.log((function(x, f = (z) => z) {
  var x;
  var y = x;
  x = 2;
  return [x, y, f(z)];
})(1, 2));
```

but this throws an error

Output is (3) [2, 1, 1] in chrome console, but (3) [2, 1, 2] in Scratch JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is the third output 1 and not 2? [...] Why is the output different here?

If the code is run as written, then the default parameter is evaluated before entering the function. So the `x` in `f = () => x` is referring to the first parameter of the function, not the `var x` defined inside of it. And since 1 was passed in to the IIFE, 1 is the value used.
Why is the output different here?
It appears that scratchJS is transpiling to an older version of javascript. This turns the code into something like this:

```
 console.log(function (x) {
    var f = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : function () {
      return x;
    };
    var x;
    var y = x;
    x = 2;
    return [x, y, f()];
  }(1));
```

Now the default value is handled by code inside the function body. Because of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), `var x` is the variable that's referred to when doing `return x`, not the x in the argument list. By the time f is called, that local variable has been set to 2, so 2 is logged.

Comment: You are absolutely right sir! I compiled the snippet on Babel using the ES2015 preset and it turned the code to what you sent. But when I turned the preset to ES2017, the code did not change at all! Your reasoning explained the different ouputs.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, `() => x` is returning 1 because you didn't pass a function as 2nd argument, that means the arrow function is instantiated outside of your function and keeps its own context. the `x` inside the function is confined to a different context.

This is a classic issue with shadowed name variables, same name but different nested context.

In the second example you are passing the value `2` as a function in your arguments, which is why it's throwing. You can't execute `2()`.